# ajax call fails in different computers

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

This ajax call works fine on my computer, mobile phone & the other windows on my vmware on my laptop (all browsers), but when I test it on my laptop's ubuntu or my other computer it doesn't work and gives error, also checked it on my friend's laptop and it worked just fine but failed when I checked it on his computer... the ajax is being called by:

```
timer = setTimeout('handleCriteria()', 500);
```

and this is the ajax preparation function:

```
function handleCriteria() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    var options = {
        url: '@Url.Action("GetAddressForCriteria", "Advertise")',
        data: { criteria: searchViewModel.criteria() },
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (dt) {
            if (dt.hasOwnProperty('result')) {
                searchViewModel.searchResult(dt.result);
                $("#searchCriteria").autocomplete("option", "source", dt.result);
                $("#searchCriteria").autocomplete("search", searchViewModel.criteria());
            }
        }
    }
    ajaxSearch(options);
```

and this is the ajax function

```
function ajaxSearch(options) {
    $.ajax(options);
}
```

The error it gives is:

```
GET http://xxxxxxxx/Advertise/GetAddressForCriteria?criteria=%D8%A7%D9%88&_=1371308761017
```

I can't debug the server side on the devices which fail the ajax call since there's no development tool is installed on them.

Comment: That's not really an error; what's in your JS console?

Comment: That's all I get from my chrome console, doesn't it mean that there's something wrong with the server side? and the strange thing is before I post this comment I just checked again and surprisingly it worked on chrome, not firefox though then I had to restart the system and again it's not working ...

Comment: No, it doesn't necessarily mean that. Have you debugged the JS? Put in console.log statements or equivalent to see what's happening? Checked the wire to see what's in the request and/or response?

Comment: I used the chrome debugger itself and it show that the error takes place at the jquery file loaded from the bundle, at line 1. Correct me if I'm wrong, if it works on the other computer and not on the other ones, could be anything else than the code itself? I also checked the request, everything seems fine but there's no response ofc